# Implicit conversion of return expressions to bool

Tags: c++, boost, implicit-conversion

When trying to build some legacy code (with a recent version of boost), I stumbled upon the following problem:

```
#include <boost/scoped_array.hpp>

bool foo(const boost::scoped_array<int> bar) {
    return bar;
}

bool foo2(const boost::scoped_array<int> bar) {
    const bool r = bar;
    return r;
}

bool foo3(const boost::scoped_array<int> bar) {
    return bar ? true : false;
}
```

The above source will not compile. Both `foo` and `foo2` are erroneous. To be precise, the expected implicit conversion from scoped_array to bool is not allowed:

```
➜  /tmp clang++ --std=c++14 testconversion.cpp -o testconversion.o
testconversion.cpp:4:12: error: no viable conversion from returned value of type 'const boost::scoped_array<int>' to function return type 'bool'
    return bar;
           ^~~
testconversion.cpp:8:16: error: no viable conversion from 'const boost::scoped_array<int>' to 'const bool'
    const bool r = bar;
```

This brings up two questions:

1. Why are foo and foo2 not valid? the [reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion) explicitly mentions:

   > when initializing a new object of type T2, including return
   >   statement in a function returning T2;
2. When was that legal. The legacy code definitely used to build with boost 1.48.0. Was there

   1. a change in the boost libraries
   2. a change to the language/compilers

Comment: So the compiler says 'erroneous'?

Comment: In way more words.

Comment: And you don't want tu bother us with them?

Comment: see the edit i made

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look inside the documentation of [`boost::scoped_array`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_64_0/libs/smart_ptr/scoped_array.htm#conversions):

> `operator unspecified-bool-type () const; // never throws`
>
> Returns an unspecified value that, when **used in boolean contexts**, is equivalent to `get() != 0`.

You have to use `static_cast` to convert your `boost::scoped_array` to `bool`:

```
bool foo(const boost::scoped_array<int>& bar) {
    return static_cast<bool>(bar);
}

bool foo2(const boost::scoped_array<int>& bar) {
    const bool r = static_cast<bool>(bar);
    return r;
}
```

Maybe just a typo but in your example you passing `boost::scoped_array` by value. It has no copy constructor, so passing it by value will also cause errors.

---

It works with Boost 1.48.0 because the [`operator_bool.hpp`](https://beta.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/boost/smart_ptr/detail/operator_bool.hpp) was different in that version. In Boost 1.64.0 the [same header](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_64_0/boost/smart_ptr/detail/operator_bool.hpp) contains `explicit operator bool () const;` which prevenst you to copy-initialize a `bool` from a `boost::scoped_array` instance when you are compiling it with `-std=c++14` (or `-std=c++11`). Your code will work with Boost 1.64.0 too if you are compiling it with `-std=c++98`.

Comment: Thanks for finding the root cause. That was very helpful.

Comment: In particular, the erroneous code assumes two implicit conversions (to `unspecified-bool-type` and then to `bool`) in a row. That's not allowed. Making the second conversion explicit solves it.